# How can I use the Von Neumann stability analysis on a system of finite difference equations?

Tags: numerical-methods, wave-equation, finite-differences, stability-theory

I am trying to numerically solve the following system of partial differential equations:

$$ k^2u_{xx} - u_{tt} = f \tag 1$$
$$ c^2f_{xx} - f_{tt} = 0 \tag 2$$

I am using the method of finite differences and the central difference approximation. I know how to use the Von-Neuman stability analysis to determine the necessary stability condition in case of a single equation. However, here I have a system of equations.

I didn't find in literature how to use the Von-Neuman analysis for a system of equations. So my question is, how would I determine the stability of my system of equations using that method? Note that inserting equation $(1)$ into $(2)$ is not the way I would like to solve this problem. Also, even though I assume that the CFL condition is the necessary condition I am looking for, I would still like to derive it.

Comment: I suppose you could write out the fourth order equation for $u$—eliminating $f$—and see where that gets you.

Comment: I think the f term on the RHS of (1) basically doesn’t matter - if f is stable, then you can just ignore it, so you can just do the standard stability thing on u and f separately.  On smaller time scales, changes in f (or errors in f) are super tiny compared to the higher order terms (which will have delta x’s or delta t’s in the denominator, making them large comparatively).  If that were higher order, you could prob just shove in lots of exponential terms and solve for them.

Comment: @Aruralreader I can, but I would prefer to solve the system of equations. Especially because I know the boundary conditions for them.

Comment: @Eric I think also that I can neglect the RHS of (1). I won't know until I finish the implementation of the code though. Still, I would like to know how to solve this type of systems.